# Find indexes of unique in a matlab vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector `M` with possibilities of multiple duplicates, and I want to create an index vector that ignores all the duplicates. I tried `[C,ia,ib] = unique(M)` but I don't quite know how to use ia and ib.

Edit: Sorry I missed an important detail, `I` is an existing index vector, it needs to get rid of all index that contain duplicate value. So the original vector looks like `M(I)` and I want to 'clean up' up `I`, if I do directly ia = I it won't preserve the original data of I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html:

> `[C,ia,ic] = unique(A)` also returns index vectors `ia` and `ic`, such that `C = A(ia)` and `A = C(ic)`.

For example:

```
[C ia ic] = unique([11 22 11 33 22 44])
```

results in:

```
C =

   11   22   33   44

ia =

   3   5   4   6

ic =

   1   2   1   3   2   4
```

**Update**

In your updated scenario, you should do `I = I(ia)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional outputs.

```
a=round(10*rand(1,10)) 

[dummy I]=unique(a,'first'); 

u=a(sort(I));
```